# Provider class in healthMonitoring gets inner exception

Tags: asp.net, exception, provider

We have Health monitoring setup for our applications. We have been facing a strange issue for some time.

When an unhandled exception in thrown in our web applications, it gets captured by the `ProcessEventMethod(WebBaseEvent raisedevent)` in our custom provider class (inheriting from `BufferedEventProvider` class).

This event is of type `WebRequestErrorEvent`. However the `ErrorException` object that is embedded in this event is the `InnerException` of the actual exception thrown.

Any reason why the header exception is not captured? This issue makes it very difficult for us to find the exact root cause of the issue? Am I doing something wrong in my configuration or do I need to code anything extra to get this fixed?

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you by any chance rethrow the error somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a very old unanswered question, but I thought that I would at least provide you with my thoughts...

You didn't provide any code samples, but I was just wondering if you are somehow swallowing the real exception? In your custom Event Type, are you calling base.Raise() in your overridden Raise method?

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.webrequesterrorevent(v=vs.110).aspx